# How can I check if an element in a table exists?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm writing a Postgres function which should delete from 3 tables successively.

The relation is delete from mobgroupdata -> mobilenums -> terminals and when I don't have an element in mobgroupdata, I want to delete from mobilenums and then from terminals. But what should be the condition. I've tried with

`IF mRec.id != 0`, but it didn't work, than I've tried with `exists`, it also didn't work. Also when I made my `select` statement from the DB and mobgroupdata's id doesn't exist, the code is breaking, but when I select element which consist in all tables it works. Does anybody know what should be the if statement to make it works?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Delete_From_Terminals_Casc_final12"(
"Id_list" bigint,
"Curuser_id" bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF term_mgd_mobnums AS
$BODY$
declare
  mRec "term_mgd_mobnums"%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    for mRec in    select mn."id_terminals", t.sn , t.imei ,t.les ,t.category ,t.model ,t.tswv ,t.status ,t.activation_date ,t.deactivation_date ,t.paytype ,t.ip_address ,t.pin1 ,t.pin2 ,t.puk1 ,t.puk2 ,t.notes ,t.units ,t.validtill, t.responsible_user,t.id_clients,t.currentuser, t.isn,
 md.id_mobilenums, mn.current_status, mn.start_date ,mn.streason ,mn.unit ,mn.mobnumber ,mn.service ,mn.status as mn_status,mn.activator ,mn.responsible_department,mn.date_changed ,mn.reason ,mn.installed_on ,mn.usedby ,mn.regnumber ,mn.responsible_user as mn_responsible_user ,mn.description,
 md.id,md.les1 ,md.les2,md.les3,md.les4,md.les5,md.member1 ,md.member2,md.member3,md.member4,md.member5,md.user1 ,md.user2,md.user3,md.user4,md.user5,md.pass1 ,md.pass2,md.pass3,md.pass4,md.pass5 from terminals t
inner join mobilenums mn on t."id" = mn."id_terminals"
inner join mobgroupdata md on md."id_mobilenums" = mn."id"
where mn."id_terminals" = $1  
loop    

 IF exists THEN
 PERFORM "Delete_From_Mobgroupdata2"(mRec.id,$2);
 PERFORM "Delete_From_Mobilenums"(mRec.id_mobilenums::text,$2);
 PERFORM "Delete_From_Terminals"(mRec.id_terminals::text,$2);
     ELSE
 PERFORM "Delete_From_Mobilenums"(mRec.id_mobilenums::text,$2);
 PERFORM "Delete_From_Terminals"(mRec.id_terminals::text,$2);
END IF;
 RETURN NEXT mRec;
   end loop;
   return;
end;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION "Delete_From_Terminals_Casc_final12"(bigint, bigint)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: This can be solved elegantly, but it's unclear to me what the precise algorithm should be. If you can clarify the question, you will surely get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your code, if I am reading  your question correctly:

1. You are using `INNER JOIN` to join to `mobgroupdata`. This will only retrieve results for rows which do exist in all of your tables. Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.
2. You tried `mRec.id != 0`, but you are looking for `NULL`, not `0`. `0` and `NULL` are not the same thing in SQL. The condition you want is `mRec.id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: If this answers your question to your satisfaction, please accept the answer by clicking on the green check mark to its left. This will mark the question as answered, and give me the pretend internet points which I crave.

Comment: Yes, this answers my question, i forgot to accept the answer, than you :)